# self sizing collectionView with flowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I use collectionView without

```
let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as!  UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize (width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
```

then all the cells are displayed but when I use flowLayout then cells are not displayed I've been sitting here for a week on this and can not understand why this is happening.

here my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)



    requestD(url: url)

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return modals.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if modals.count == 0 {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellAudio


    cell.name?.text = modals[indexPath.row].name


    let u = URL(string: "http://www.---.com" + (modals[indexPath.row].ImageViewURL))
    cell.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: u, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "white"),
                               options: [.continueInBackground,.scaleDownLargeImages]) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in

                                self.modals[indexPath.row].ImageView = cell.ImageView.image!

    }  

    return cell  
}

func requestD(url:String){


    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 300



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error ?? 0)
            return
        }
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]

            if let main = json["LIBRARY"] as? [String:[String : Any]]{

                for (_, data) in main {
                    let info = ModalAudio()
                    info.id = data["ID"] as? String
                    info.name = data["NAME"] as? String
                    info.AboutBook = data["DETAIL_TEXT"] as? String
                    info.ImageViewURL = data["PICTURE"] as! String

                    self.modals.append(info)


                }
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            self.isMoreDataLoading = false
            self.iNumPage += 1

        }
    }

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `viewDidLoad` the frame of your collection view is undefined yet, so put this code in your `viewDidLayoutSubView` method, after reviewing your project your issues is related to use of `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize` as you can read in the property declaration comment

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
open var estimatedItemSize: CGSize // defaults to CGSizeZero - setting a non-zero size enables cells that self-size via -preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:
```

So use this code, **it works**!

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

            //flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100) don't show your cells
            flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)//show your cells
            flowLayout.invalidateLayout() 
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Vasya2014 is a real project or example one? can you post your project in github to review it?

Comment: This is a project. I can make an example project in a couple of hours.  Will it be convenient for you?

Comment: @Vasya2014 perfect, Iam going to sleep, if you post me an example i will review and fix this, I will be back in 7hrs

Comment: CollectionViewController does not want to display cells when I use flowLayout and so everything works fine

Comment: Cells are displayed but the size does not change depending on the text, constrains put down from the top

Comment: Found the reason?

Comment: @Vasya2014 I have a lot of work, but I will review it as soon as i can, sorry

Comment: I'm so embarrassed but I still have not solved the problem

Comment: @Vasya2014 sorry, I will try it today if i have some time, this is an unfinished business for me

Comment: @Vasya2014 your priority is the Image Size or the text size? or the image size is static?

Comment: The size of the image is fixed, the text size changes

Comment: @Vasya2014 let me know if this is what you need http://imgur.com/dCydiZq

Comment: Yes this is what I need

Comment: thanks, I downloaded the project, you can delete the link to the project so that others would not download it?

Comment: @Vasya2014 of course its your project, i will remove also the github project

Comment: Your welcome, let me know if helps you, when I have some time i will update the answer and post a second variant @Vasya2014

Comment: Why you say that? It's the project I download from your posted link

Comment: the project is the same, there nothing has changed as you showed in the picture

Comment: check did you checkout the first approach branch? @Vasya2014

Comment: very strange, can separately send the code that you wrote?

Comment: Which viewController are you testing @Vasya2014?

Comment: each separately

Comment: @Vasya2014 check in CollectionViewCellSearch and post the line # 21

Comment: there ImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154239/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-vasya2014).

Comment: @ReinierMelian  Have you got the solution. I tried it but not work Its look likee Pinterest layout but not work..  can you help me